# Upgraded to 3.8.1 on wp-admin but unable to upgrade in godaddy cpanel

Tags: upgrade, theme-twenty-twelve

Godaddy is unable to help me with this one as it is a wp related issue.

Basically, I've been upgrading WP through the wp-amdin panel. And in the meantime, the WP Application on godaddy has stayed at 3.7. And now I am for some reason unable to upgrade it in godaddy. I can revert it to 3.6.1 and then it gives a message to upgrade to 3.8.1 and when I attempt to do that, it doesn't upgrade all the way, just up to 3.7 and then it stalls.

- Any thoughts what might be going on here?
- Does this mean that WP is actually not upgraded, even though on the wp-admin side it's upgraded.
- I have tried removing all the plugins and doing the same process and it still it didn't work.
- The theme is twenty-twelve, the child files were edited a lot before I joined the project, could it be that these might be causing the problem.
  The website is overall super slow and some plugins are very slow and slowing the site down. So I'd like to make sure it's not because WP is not up to date.

I hope I provided enough info, let me know if you'd like any more specifics and thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have upgraded to WordPress 3.8.1 properly using your website admin panel.

The problem is that GoDaddy thinks that you should do everything through them rather than you being able to think for yourself.

In the same area where you have been trying to upgrade WordPress through GoDaddy there should be a link that allows you to manually update the version you are using. Just tell their system that you are already using version 3.8.1 and you will be all set.

It's not necessary to do anything with GoDaddy to keep your WordPress website up to date, but by manually letting them know the version you are using it may stop them from giving you warnings about using out of date software (when you are not).